# How to compare specific number of words among two lists of strings in Python

Tags: python

I need to write a script that takes two sentences as input and verifies if they contains exactly four words that are equal. My code follow doesn't work as I have limited knowledge and I really value your knowledge!

I want to test if there are four distinct words in common.

```
input1 = "The winter season is cold and wet but snow is cool".split()

input2 = "The summer season is hot and humid but sun is shining".split()


count = 0
i = 1
input3 = []
while i == 4:
    for i in range(len(input1)):
        for j in range(len(input2)):
            if i in j:
                if j in i:
                    input3.append(i and j)
                    count += 1
```

Comment: Split each line into words and convert to set, then join both sets into another set. If length of set is 4, you have 4 distinct words. Loops is overkill for this

Comment: Are you testing if there are 4 *distinct* words in common, or do you take the number of times a word appears into account?

Comment: @JohnColeman I am testing if there are 4 distinct words in common

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a nested for loop would work. Try this:

```py
input1 = "The winter season is cold and wet but snow is cool".split()
input2 = "The summer season is hot and humid but sun is shining".split()

input3 = []

for i in input1:
    for x in input2:
        if i == x:
            input3.append(i)

input3 = list(dict.fromkeys(input3)) #This removes duplicates from the list. Delete it if you want duplicates
if len(input3) == 4:
    print("Contains 4 Words")
    
print(input3)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)s are great for this. No need for writing loops:

```
input1 = "The winter season is cold and wet but snow is cool"
input2 = "The summer season is hot and humid but sun is shining"

distinct_words = set.intersection(*map(set, map(str.split, (input1, input2))))

print(len(distinct_words))
```

---

```
5
```

You could always just use the intersection operator as well:

```
len(set(input1.split()) & set(input2.split()))
```

---

```
5
```

Comment: Why not just `len(set(input1) & set(input2))` ?

Comment: Thats what I was suggesting. Best answer as the data is not too big

Comment: It does, although OP said they wanted 2 inputs as strings not as lists. The fact that they turn them into lists in that line is misleading code as the split at the end can be missed while reading the code. Although the `&` works this is more appropriate to what OP said. I'll edit with that too.